# phpDocumenter and abstract methods

Tags: php, phpdoc

I'm using phpDocumentor

> phpDocumentor version 2.0.0a10`

and have several `abstract` classes that I am documenting. **The documentation seems to include those `abstract class`es but not methods that are `abstract`.** I usually heavily document abstract methods to explain the contract and my vision for how it will be implemented across different use cases. Is there a setting that I'm missing in phpdoc that will force it to document these?

Comment: @sixeightzero `PHP 5.3.13`, would love to jump to 5.4, some of our legacy code breaks :(

Answer (score 0):

This is how your abstract class could look with proper docblock.

```
/**
* login method
*
* Abstract method that must be implemented when
* sub-classing this class.
*
* @access public
* @return boolean
*/
abstract public function login($user, $password);
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately the issue was that phpDocumentor was not including the documentation that I wrote, not that I didn't know how to document.